# Background is turning out black

Tags: php, background, merge, gd, transparent

I have done everything I could possibly try to fix this. I've spent over an hour researching and trying code, but nothing has helped.

This code does the following.

- Take two completely-white images and re-color them (**while keeping transparency**)
- Merge the two images together
- Outputs the images (but **with** a black background!!)

Can someone help identify and patch the part that's causing the black background? See the following URL for an example of the script.

- http://labs.bluefiremedia.net/metro-machine/gd/download-png.php?size=128&padding=29&icon=icons/Application/Add-New.png&bgShape=CircleBG.png&bgColorR=255&bgColorG=0&bgColorB=0&iconColorR=255&iconColorG=255&iconColorB=255

  ```
  $final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dimensions, $dimensions);
  imagesavealpha($final_image, true);

  if($bgShape != '') {
  list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize('../images/' . $bgShape);

  $background = imagecreatefrompng('../images/' . $bgShape);

  imagefilter($background, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, -255);
  imagefilter($background, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $bgColorR, $bgColorG, $bgColorB);

  $backgroundImage = imagecreatetruecolor( $dimensions, $dimensions );
  imagealphablending($backgroundImage , false);
  imagesavealpha($backgroundImage , true);

  imagecopyresampled($backgroundImage,
      $background,
      0, 0,
      0, 0,
      $dimensions, $dimensions,
      $originalWidth, $originalHeight
  );

  imagecopy($final_image, $backgroundImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dimensions, $dimensions);

  ///

  $icon = imagecreatefrompng("../" . $icon);

  imagefilter($icon, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, -255);
  imagefilter($icon, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $iconColorR, $iconColorG, $iconColorB);

  $iconImage = imagecreatetruecolor( $dimensions, $dimensions );
  imagealphablending($iconImage , false);
  imagesavealpha($iconImage , true);

  imagecopyresampled($iconImage,
      $icon,
      0, 0,
      0, 0,
      $dimensions, $dimensions,
      $originalWidth, $originalHeight
  );

  imagecopy($final_image, $iconImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dimensions, $dimensions);

  ///

  imagealphablending($final_image, true);
  imagesavealpha($final_image, true);

  imagepng($final_image, NULL, 0, PNG_NO_FILTER);

  header("Content-type: image/png");
  imagedestroy($backgroundImage);
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `imagealphablending` to false, fill your image with a transparent color, set `imagealphablending` to true, then do your copying stuff.

```
$final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dimensions, $dimensions);
imagealphablending($final_image, false);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($final_image,  0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($final_image, 0, 0, $dimensions, $dimensions, $transparency);
imagesavealpha($final_image, true);
imagealphablending($final_image, true);

// rest of the code
```